# How to select and display multiple data related to one ID

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have two tables : one for storing employer details and the other one for storing experience that employer may ask from job seekers.

It has one to many relationship which means each employer may ask many experiences from job seekers.

My questions are:
How to select and display records using an array?
How to display more experiences for one employer?

[image: Employer details]

[image: Experience table]

Comment: Please also give details what do you want in result output.

Comment: I need to display the job_tit, com_name, location and experinces. Multiple experinces each employer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Inner join

SELECT * FROM employer emp inner join experience e on e.job_id=emp.job_id;